# Difference between to Tensor products with regards to modules

Tags: modules, representation-theory, tensor-products

What would be the difference between $$ \otimes_B $$  and $$ \otimes $$ both in the following context and in general?

Let A be a ring with $$ B \subset A $$ and M a B-Module. We can construct the induced module $$ Ind_B^A M = A \otimes_B M $$ as the quotient of a free abelian group with generators
from A × M by relations

$$(a_1+a_2)×m=a_1×m−a_2×m,a×(m_1+m_2)=a×m_1−a×m_2,ab×m=a×bm
$$

Why is $$ \otimes_B $$ different to $$\otimes$$ ?

Source: http://math.berkeley.edu/~serganov/math252/notes4.pdf

Comment: $\otimes$ by itself only has meaning if it somewhere says that it is taken to mean $\otimes_R$ for some fixed $R$.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft OK, so in this case as $$\otimes$$ is defined over B rather than A with B in A. Does this mean $$\otimes$$ acts differently?  I have previously only see case of tensor product being taken over the largest object.

Comment: What do you mean the largest object? In this case, you have two $B$-modules, so you tensor over $B$. There would not be any way to tensor over something larger a priori.

Comment: The subscript of the $\otimes$ symbol signifies what kind of factors you're allowed to move from one term to the other in the tensor product. So usually, the bigger the subscript group / ring, the smaller the resulting tensor product (more terms are considered equivalent). Of course, you have to make sure that it makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Tobias said, when you see something like $M \otimes N$ with unadorned tensor product where $M$ and $N$ are modules, what's usually happening is that there is some standard fixed base ring that is being suppressed in the notation. For instance, rather than rings I generally work with algebras over some field $k$ - for me $\otimes$ is always $\otimes_k$, whereas all other tensor products need to state what ring they're over explicitly. It's important to know what ring you're working over because tensoring by a different base ring usually gets you a different answer! For instance, $\mathbb{C} \otimes_\mathbb{C} \mathbb{C}$ is something different from $\mathbb{C} \otimes_\mathbb{R} \mathbb{C}$. Anyway, it depends on the context you're working in.

However, reading through the notes you linked I actually can't see an example of that happening. Instead, what I suspect may be confusing you is that it's convention to use the unadorned tensor product for elements: so in your example, given $a \in A, m \in M$, we can consider the element in $A \otimes_B M$ that corresponds to the equivalence class of $a \times m$ in the free abelian group with respect to the appropriate relations for the tensor product. That is generally written $a \otimes m$. I don't think it's common for people to write $a \otimes_B m$ and the notes you linked don't - I guess because when you're working with elements you know what object they're from and hence what base ring the tensor product is respect to.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this partially explains it but it seems that my misunderstanding is also deeper. Would it be possible for you to explicitly explain the difference between $\mathbb{C} \otimes_{\mathbb{R}} \mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{C} \otimes_{\mathbb{C}} \mathbb{C}$ or point me to a resource?

Comment: The easy way to see this: in $\mathbb{C} \otimes_{\mathbb{C}} \mathbb{C}$, you're allowed to take any complex number through the tensor product, but in $\mathbb{C} \otimes_\mathbb{R} \mathbb{C}$ you can only do that with real numbers. So $1 \otimes i$ and $i \otimes 1$ are not equal/in the same equivalence class when tensoring over $\mathbb{R}$, but they are over $\mathbb{C}$. A vector space dimension argument also tells you that the tensor product over $\mathbb{C}$ has two real dimensions but the one over $\mathbb{R}$ has four. Does that help?